# SAP EWM standard reports

Tags: report, s4hana, sap-ewm

Can somebody list an SAP EWM standard reports that are used today in S/4HANA?

I know that in S/4HANA in tcode /SCM/MON you can monitor the warehouse but I can't find the list with all the reports.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Blazko,
Yes you are right /SCWM/MON is the central tool for understanding processes in SAP EWM:

- Physical Stock,
- Available Stock,
- Inbound / Outbound deliveries
- etc.

Other useful EWM transactions you can find on [SAP WIKI](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SCM/EWM+Transaction+Codes)

And I don't know about other standart reports.
This area for custom (Z*) programming.

For example  two  custom common Zxxxx reports via ABAP:

- Compare stock from EWM and from our non-SAP ERP system
- Stock with expiring shelf life